# How to create debian package for a java project?

Tags: java, packaging, deb, jar

I have written a small gui for btrfs called [TimeTraveler](https://github.com/stoiandan/TimeTraveler). And export it as `.jar` file. How do I package it as  a `.deb` file for Ubuntu?